# How to fetch latest Apple podcast date with Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with Apple Podcasts URLs.

[image]

What I want to do is to get newest podcast date.

[image]

So basically content of "sort-value" tag of first grid cell element:

```
<td role="gridcell" sort-value="2017/12/22" class="release-date">
```

Can it be done with **IMPORTHTML** function?

Example podcast URL: https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/modern-sewciety-podcast/id742393907

Comment: @pnuts Sorry for that. I fixed formatting and added images, hope it's better now. If you have any suggestions that could make this question even better please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//td[@class='release-date']//span[@class='text']"), 1)
```

- `https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/modern-sewciety-podcast/id742393907` is in a cell "A1".
- XPath is `//td[@class='release-date']//span[@class='text']`.
- The top value is retrieved using `INDEX`.

[image]

### Edit :

About the reason that the value of cell becomes `43091`, It is considered that it is due to the cell format. In order to modify this situation, please try the following 2 patterns.

1. Modify the format for the cell with `43091`.

   - On the spreadsheet, please select "Format" -> "Number" -> "Date"
   - If you want to other date format, please customize it.
2. Use this XPath.

   - `=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//td[@class='release-date']/@sort-value"), 1)`
   - In this XPath, the format of date is different from `//td[@class='release-date']//span[@class='text']`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate. I'm getting different number then date: https://i.imgur.com/eLaGpZi.png

Comment: @J. Baptiste I'm sorry for the inconvenience and my incomplete answer. I updated my answer, please confirm it.

Comment: No worries, you helped me a lot! However I have one more issue as  [one podcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/american-patchwork-and-quilting-radio/id435717297) site seems to [exceeded maximum size](https://i.imgur.com/3yZeQ6k.png), do you know if there any workaround for it?

Comment: @J. Baptiste I'm sorry. It seems that your next issue is the difference from your initial question. Can you post it as a new question by including the detail information? By this, more users will be able to think of your solution and workaround. At that time, when your initial question had been solved, please accept this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give the specifics for Google Sheets, but I can tell you that you can more quickly get this data from using the Apple Media Lookup API.

Using the ID number, 742393907, make a call to this API endpoint: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=742393907

That will return the following JSON:

```json
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "kind": "podcast",
            "collectionId": 742393907,
            "trackId": 742393907,
            "artistName": "Stephanie Kendron: Modern Creative blogger and podcaster",
            "collectionName": "Modern Sewciety Podcast",
            "trackName": "Modern Sewciety Podcast",
            "collectionCensoredName": "Modern Sewciety Podcast",
            "trackCensoredName": "Modern Sewciety Podcast",
            "collectionViewUrl": "https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/modern-sewciety-podcast/id742393907?uo=4",
            "feedUrl": "http://www.modernsewciety.com/feed/podcast",
            "trackViewUrl": "https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/modern-sewciety-podcast/id742393907?uo=4",
            "artworkUrl30": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/db/f3/1d/dbf31d7f-3fae-84a6-c4b6-91adebc2394d/mza_4725542195606703711.jpg/30x30bb.jpg",
            "artworkUrl60": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/db/f3/1d/dbf31d7f-3fae-84a6-c4b6-91adebc2394d/mza_4725542195606703711.jpg/60x60bb.jpg",
            "artworkUrl100": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/db/f3/1d/dbf31d7f-3fae-84a6-c4b6-91adebc2394d/mza_4725542195606703711.jpg/100x100bb.jpg",
            "collectionPrice": 0.00,
            "trackPrice": 0.00,
            "trackRentalPrice": 0,
            "collectionHdPrice": 0,
            "trackHdPrice": 0,
            "trackHdRentalPrice": 0,
            "releaseDate": "2020-03-08T16:39:00Z",
            "collectionExplicitness": "cleaned",
            "trackExplicitness": "cleaned",
            "trackCount": 50,
            "country": "USA",
            "currency": "USD",
            "primaryGenreName": "Design",
            "contentAdvisoryRating": "Clean",
            "artworkUrl600": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/db/f3/1d/dbf31d7f-3fae-84a6-c4b6-91adebc2394d/mza_4725542195606703711.jpg/600x600bb.jpg",
            "genreIds": [
                "1402",
                "26",
                "1301"
            ],
            "genres": [
                "Design",
                "Podcasts",
                "Arts"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You would want the `releaseDate` field, which is pulled from the podcast's latest episode.